# Link options are incompatible - don't see options anywhere in command

Tags: linux, linker, g++

`g++ -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -o /path-to/executable {list of .o files} -L/usr/X11R6/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lQtGui -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/openwin/lib -lSM -lICE -lXext -lX11 -lresolv -lsocket -lnsl -lQtCore -lm -lrt -ldl -lpthread`

I'm using the above command to compile an executable. Well actually a makefile is doing it for me..but regardless.

I'm getting an error with the above command:

```
ld: fatal: option -dn and -P are incompatible
ld: fatal: Flags processing errors
```

I don't see where -dn or -P are being supplied to the linker anywhere in the command or in the makefile. Where is the linker getting this info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By trying to temporarily remove each segment of the linking command, I found that removing "`,rpath,/usr/local/lib`" made the thing work. Which got me thinking that I was setting linker options somewhere else in linux world.

Further investigation proved that I was setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH which included some linker options that caused the conflict. Upon changing that LD_LIBRARY_PATH, things worked as they should have.

Answer (score 0):

`-Wl,-rpath` seems to cause the `-dn` option on the linker on Solaris.

`-dn` sets static linking which is incompatible with dynamic options.

For the path `/usr/local/lib`:

- `-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib` can be replaced with:
- `-R/usr/local/lib` on Solaris
- `-L/usr/local/lib` on AIX.